# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'rides'

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I am getting this error but do not getting where I am wrong.

the routes are as follows,

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register-user', component: RegisterUserComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'dash', component: SideNavComponent,
  children: [
    {path: 'rides', component: RidesComponent,  pathMatch: 'full'}
  ]}];
```

the app.component.html is,

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

SideNavComponent HTML is,

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport="true"
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar> 
      <div class="logo-container">
      <img src="/assets/images/Yaana-logo-white.png" class="logoDiv"/>
      </div>  
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
      <nav class="sidenavbutton">
        <button class="cmpbtn" mat-button (click)="onUserInfoClicked()">User Info<mat-icon id="icon">{{userInfoIcon}}</mat-icon></button>
        <ul class="subbtn" *ngIf="showUserSubs === true">
            <li class="sub-menu"> <a routerLink="/rides" routerLinkActive="active">Rides </a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="accent">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span></span>
    </mat-toolbar>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

The SideNavComponent contains  to display the child components of SideNavComponent below the toolbar.

But when I am trying to Navigate to RidesComponent as

> http://localhost:4200/dash/rides

, I am getting the following error,

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'rides'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1359)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1340)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1359)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1340)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:33)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3662)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Please correct me where I am wrong.

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials, I found out the solution, it was the issue with the routerlink part,

this is the change I have made,

```
 <li class="sub-menu"> <a routerLink="rides" routerLinkActive="active">Rides </a></li>
```

Now this works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why

```
<a routerLink="rides" routerLinkActive="active">Rides </a></li>
```

worked and

```
<a routerLink="/rides" routerLinkActive="active">Rides </a></li>
```

this didn't is that,

First one is a relative path where as the second one is absolute path.

So when you click on the first link, angular appends the routerLink to the current path, where as in the second one, angular appends it to the application context root, not taking the current url into consideration.

I hope somebody benefits from this. :).

Answer (score 0):

It seem you forget to add `<base href="/">`.Please add this in **index.html**.

Comment: I have added it. No issue with that I think

Answer (score 0):

`{path: 'rides', component: RidesComponent}`  will serve the purpose, you don't need  `pathMatch: 'full'` here, rest looks good to me.

Comment: I have experienced a strange behaviour,  Please some one explain, when I Open the link from this question page it worked perfectlty fine, but when I am testing through ng serve , it is throwing that error.

Comment: Could you please provide complete code sample at https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: it's opening from here because you insisted to match full path in your route configuration.

Comment: No, I have removed it from the routes, i.e I remove match full path from the ride component

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="sub-menu"> <a routerLink="/dash/rides" routerLinkActive="active">Rides </a></li>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.